# find in set in laravel ? example

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am new in laravel. My query is i need to find out value from comma separated field.

Here is my table:

**tags_value**

| id | tags |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | css,html,php |
| 2 | php,java,css |
| 3 | java,c++,ios |

This is my SQL query:

```
$query = DB::table('tags_value')
         ->whereRaw(FIND_IN_SET('css', Tags))
         ->get();
```

but it's not working.

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: i got this error Call to undefined function App\FIND_IN_SET()

Comment: Laravel thinks you are trying to call a function called `FIND_IN_SET()`, which does not exist.  Escape the entire `whereRaw` clause in quotes.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to escape the call to `FIND_IN_SET()` using quotes:

```php
$query = DB::table('tags_value')
    ->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET("css", Tags)')
    ->get();
```

But unless it's a fixed value, you should *always* parameterize the column for which you search in `FIND_IN_SET`:

```php
$searchvalue = 'css';
$query = DB::table('tags_value')
    ->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(?, Tags)', [$searchvalue])
    ->get();
```

Comment: perfect answer.
Just little correction; 'css' is not the column name but the value - so you are parameterizing the value here
to parameterize the column use 
$colname = 'Tags'
$query = DB::table('tags_value')
         ->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(css,?)', [$colname])
         ->get();

Comment: @WillKoz you don't parameterize column names, only string and integer values can be parameterized. I corrected the potentially misleading variable name.

Answer (score 7):

Try this :

```
->whereRaw("FIND_IN_SET('css',tags)")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DB::table('tags_value')->whereRaw("find_in_set('php',tags)")....
```

Note that while using  `find_in_set()` with **Laravel  Eloquent** `.find_in_set('.$tags.',columnName)`. sometime we become confuse that where we need give **variable** and **db column name**.

Answer (score -1):

How to use find in set in laravel with passing dynamic value to eloquent. 100% work.

```
$restaurants = Restaurant::whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET("'.$request->code.'",restaurant_code)')->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I have done it:

```
$value = '2';
Vendor::whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET("'.$value.'",service_industries)')->count();
```