# OctoberCMS db query and json

Tags: php, mysql, json, octobercms

I have db table **categories** with columns

```
id name types active
```

- ID - INT, auto increment
- NAME - VARCHAR
- TYPES - JSONABLE
- ACTIVE - INT

DB record example

```
1 | Test Category | ["1","2"] | 1
2 | Another One | ["1","2","3"] | 1
```

Now i want to create a query to get category is active = 1 and type is in array (from **types** column).

For example my type is **3** and query should look if **3** exist in ["1","2","3"]

```
$categories = Db::table('categories')
    ->where('types', '3') <- ??
    ->where('active', 1)
    ->get();
```

How can i do it?

Comment: You are looking for [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set). Don't know OctoberCMS, but my guess is it will be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594450/find-in-set-in-laravel-example

Answer (score 0):

And once again i am answering my own questions. After quite few atempts to solve it in component i have simply made it work in partial using Twig function.

So the answer is:

**Query**

```
$categories = Category::where('active', 1)->get();
```

**Function in partial**

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {% if type in category.types %}
        {{ category.name }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Now it perfectly shows only categories where type (in this case **3**) is in jsonable column (as per my explanation in question).