# How do I query that is an array with another array in Laravel?

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent

I have a form that will post an array of up to 8 items, and in my database I have a column that contains an array that can also have up to 8 items, how do I query the database?

I have thought about doing a loop through the items and appending a ->where function to the query, but I don't think that's a good way of doing it.

Comment: *"how do I query the database"* - what do you want to get in the end?

Comment: @Tarasovych So it's a user table, and they have tags which are stored as comma separated string, I have an input array of tags and I want to search for users.

Comment: Use `array_search`

Comment: How tags are connected with users? Please, provide DB schema or Eloquent relations, or something else

Comment: You've to use find_in_set ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594450/find-in-set-in-laravel-example