# How do I get the badges that the user has?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table called badges and I have a JSON field with user_id that will have the users id, I put them there manually just to test it.

```
["1", "2"]
```

How would I retrieve the badges that the user has?

Something like this :

```
$items = DB::table('badges')->whereIn('user_id', [1])->get();
dd($items);
```

But my dd comes empty!

Comment: have you thought about using a pivot table instead of trying to hold an array of user ids in a field?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594450/find-in-set-in-laravel-example/35594503

Answer (score -1):

Your method is wrong, for your `badges table`, use another sub_table to store all `user_id` related to your badges.
Use your `badge_id` as a foreign key inside your `sub_table`.

Comment: Does anyone have any youtube video close to this? I would really apreciate it.

Comment: @MigueldeSousaFerreira Check these links: 
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=laravel+migration        

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSQcmcu6yHc